# Do people in US really work 9-5?

Tags: united-states, work-time

I live in western europe and the usual office time is 9:00 - 18:00, with 1h break.
I've heard so many times that in the US people work 9-5 but the math doesn't adds up: do people in US work less than 40h (8x5days) a week?
Is there a paid lunch-break?
I read [This related question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10792/8-to-5-vs-9-to-5-as-acceptable-regular-work-hours) but didn't quite understand what's the nowadays standard.

Comment: Most of this depends on the company and industry.

Comment: 9-5 five days a week is exactly 40 hours if your lunch is paid. Many companies have a paid 30 minute - 60 minute lunch break. If you didn't have a paid lunch break you would have to work 9-5:30 to hit 40 hours. It depends on the company. 38 hours is fairly common to work for people for this reason.

Comment: @DetectivePikachu yeah, but I never heard of someone's 1h lunch break paid - that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Its rare but it exists. For the most part lunch breaks are 30 minutes though, but again it depends on the company.

Comment: For some statistics related to working-hours have a look [here](https://ourworldindata.org/working-hours)..

Comment: I work 9-5 (or a variation of) with a paid lunch break and I'm UK. My last company was 9-5.30 with an hour unpaid lunch. It varies massively depending on company, even in the UK

Comment: "Working 8 to 5" or "Working 9 to 6" just doesn't have the same ring to it when Dolly Parton sings it.

Comment: I think 9-5 is just an expression. I work 8.30-5 with a 30 minute lunch break.

Comment: Well, you get into the office at 8. Then have a coffee, greet the team, boot up your PC, take a restroom break (you just had a coffee, remember?), etc. In the end, you only start working at 9. :)

Comment: Most jobs I've had have been 8 to 5 with an hour for lunch. In New York City 9 to 5 with paid lunch is common. As New York produces a lot of the media, I think the New York practice is heard about more often.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Do people in US work less than 40h (8x5days) a week? Is there a paid
>   lunch-break?

Some do. Some don't.

Everywhere I have ever worked had unpaid lunch breaks. Usually that meant working 8:00 - 17:00 or the equivalent or more.

Most salaried people I have worked with, work more than 40 hours per week.

Comment: For those that don't typically use 24 hour notation 17:00 actually is 5 PM.

Answer (score 2):

I've always heard of 9-5 too and I live in the US. However, most "banker hours" companies I have worked for have the hours of 8-5, with one hour lunch unpaid.